# Extend url parametr using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, parameters, url-rewriting

There is number of similar .htaccess questions, but even after lengthy search I haven't been able to find an answer to my problem.

I recon it should be fairly simple, it's just beyond my abilities.

I need to redirect add a parameter to extend search parametr with another - specifically I need this:

**www.domain.com/?s=whatever**

to become

**www.domain.com/?s=whatever&post_type=product**

each and every time, but obviously only when *s* parameter is present and *post_type* parameter is not.

Doing this the right way (managing the parameters at input) is unfortunately impossible in this case, that's why I want to bypass this with .htaccess.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why not have that as the default in server side language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?post_type=product [QSA,L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your insanely fast answer, it worked :) !